# Storing PIN codes

Tags: passwords

Given an application where users identify themselves by some id with an accompanying PIN code, how should PIN codes be saved?

The PIN codes are fixed length (6) and comprised entirely of digits. Once an account is selected, this pin code will be entered into pos terminals for authentication.

It is best of course, not to save the pin codes in the database as raw text. However, even good password storage techniques (ex bcrypt) seems to fall short. Due to the nature of pins, it is trivial to simply try all possibilities. (Ex try 000000-999999 on a given bcrypt hash). Is there a better way of saving PINs then?

Comment: Added more details. Tnx

Comment: Can you please clarify if PIN is the only protection (usually PIN used along with other piece of info like account name/credit card number/whatever as second authentication piece)? If PIN used as second piece of auth do you have first piece handy to brute force?

Comment: Clarified this one on my question. The PIN is entered after account selection is done. The worry is more on the assumption that a security breach takes place and the pin hashes and account id's were leaked. Given the hashes, it becomes trivial just to try out all possibilities.

Comment: Storing all information along with hashed PIN sound like a problem. To my understanding with PINs usually at least one other piece need to be provided by a user and hence makes guessing much harder (and easier to stop if you can't get to data directly). So you concerns are pretty valid. You may consider if posting your question on security SE is on-topic as there are more people who directly work with such problems. I.e. there is related discussion in http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61814/password-strength-and-banks-4-pin-code/61899#61899 .

Comment: You are right that even slow hash algorithms like BCrypt cannot protect such weak "passwords". There is another question [How would you store a 4 digit pin code](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/6719/8343) like yours on information security.